# jQuery .click() doesn't seem to actuate the unchecking of radio boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to dynamically create a reset button on radio boxes and then have said reset button uncheck any existing choice when the user clicks the button, yet when I click it, nothing happens. I'm probably missing something obvious but not sure what.

http://jsfiddle.net/sFUBV/5/

```
$('.surveyor_radio').parent().parent().append('<div class="reset-button">A reset button</div>');

$('.reset-button').click(function () {
    $('#form input[type="radio":checked]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});

$('fieldset').each(function () {
    var qid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.reset-button', $(this)).attr('data-question-id', qid);
});
```

Comment: Show us some code, so that we can have a chance to spot the obvious.

Comment: Code added. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#form input[type="radio":checked]')
```

with

```
$('#form input[type="radio"]:checked')
```

However, observe that your code doesn't discriminate between groups of radio buttons, and will simply uncheck ALL radio buttons in the entire form.

Fortunately, you already have the `data-question-id` stored on the radio button, so we can use that to provide a context instead of `#form`:

```
$('.reset-button').click(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked','#'+$(this).data('question-id')).each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sFUBV/10/

As nzifnab pointed out, we can even simplify further:

```
$('.reset-button').click(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]','#'+$(this).data('question-id')).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Did the replace, yet, after selecting an answer, clicking the "A reset button" does nothing still

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't contain a `#form` element. Try http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/sFUBV/8/ instead.

Comment: You are right, I cut and pasted it as a manageable section of a larger form, and didn't notice that it wasn't there. Thanks. Works great now.

Comment: Updated answer to solve the "don't reset ALL radio buttons" bug.

Comment: The `.each`, `:checked` pseudo-selector, and `data('question-id')` are not necessary to get the same functionality.  See my answer.

Comment: @nzifnab True enough; I usually try to modify an OP's code as little as possible. However, I'll leave in the `data('question-id')` so that the HTML can be rearranged without requiring a rewrite of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `removeAttr`, the `prop` method should suffice.

You shouldn't have to use `.each` either since most jquery methods called on jquery collections will already be executed on each object of said collection.

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/sFUBV/14/

```
$('.surveyor_radio').parent().parent().append('<div class="reset-button">A reset button</div>');

$('.reset-button').on('click', function () {
  $(this).
    closest('li.input').
    find('input[type=radio]').
    prop('checked', false);
});
```

There's no reason to add a `:checked` selector, since you're unchecking them all anyway what's it matter if you uncheck one that's not checked?  Same thing happens either way.

Note also that you don't necessarily have to do it by question-id as the accepted answer indicates.  This simply looks at all radio buttons within the current `li.input`, so you could use this anywhere without having to worry about question id's and interpolation nonsense.

Also you should be using `on` to bind events as opposed to `click` or `live`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sFUBV/9/

Answer (score 0):

try this line instead of each() function

```
$('.reset-button').click(function () {
    $('#form input[type="radio"]:checked').prop('checked', false);
});
```